# Encuesta para desarrolladores 2020: ¿Alguna sugerencia de tema?

Tags: discusión, encuesta-para-desarrolladores, anuncios-de-comunidad

> *Traducción de* [2020 Developer Survey: any topic suggestions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389461/3739416)

*Soy Anita, una Gerente de Producto aquí en Stack Overflow*

Estamos comenzando a trabajar en el cuestionario de la Encuesta para Desarrolladores 2020. Gracias a ti, tuvimos algunas buenas preguntas en la encuesta de 2019, como:

- [En promedio, ¿Cuántas horas por semana trabaja?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#work-_-hours-worked-per-week)
- [¿A qué edad escribiste tu primera línea de código o programa?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-writing-that-first-line-of-code)
- [¿Tu empresa emplea regularmente pruebas unitarias en el desarrollo de sus productos?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#work-_-unit-tests)

(Consulta los [resultados de la encuesta de 2019 <sup>en inglés</sup>](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019) si aún no lo ha hecho).

Nos encantaría recibir tus sugerencias sobre temas interesantes que deberíamos cubrir este año.

- Es el décimo aniversario de la Encuesta para Desarrolladores. ¿Alguna pregunta sobre cómo han cambiado las cosas en la última década?
- Siempre estamos en busca de preguntas divertidas/tontas, en la tradición de [haber intentado apagarlo y volverlo a encender](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-families-and-it-support) y [tabuladores vs. espacios](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#work-_-tabs-or-spaces).

Nuestro objetivo es una encuesta mucho más corta este año, por lo que no podemos incluir todas las ideas, pero siempre tratamos de incluir algunas de las sugerencias más votadas.

Como siempre, ¡Gracias por tu tiempo y contribuciones! **Por favor agrega tus sugerencias antes del Martes 1 de Octubre.**

---

[image: Encuesta para desarrolladores]

Como comunidad hispanohablante también podemos contribuir con algunas de las preguntas para la encuesta. Si deseas hacerlo, por favor, puedes hacerlo aquí en el apartado de respuestas con tu pregunta y posibles respuestas y su traducción al ingles (opcional) o si lo prefieres puedes publicar una respuesta (en ingles) directamente en: [2020 Developer Survey: any topic suggestions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389461/3739416).

Comment: Tal vez deberías añadir al principio de la publicación que las sugerencias deberían ir en la publicación original, dado que no creo que lo que aqui se proponga llegue a los destinatarios que decidirán las nuevas preguntas.

Comment: ¿Y de qué sirve ponerlo aquí? Supongo que solo se tendrán en cuenta las preguntas que se publiquen en el *post* original. ¿O la idea es llevarlas luego allí si tienen bastante aceptación? Si es así estaría bien indicarlo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 14):

Yo no tengo sugerencias sobre preguntas que hacer, pero sí tengo sugerencias sobre qué preguntas dejar de hacer:

Basta de preguntas sobre [orientación sexual](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-sexual-orientation), [raza o etnia](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-race-and-ethnicity), ["minorías"](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-gender) o [minusvalías](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-disability-status); estas preguntas no entran dentro de la categoría "*técnico-humorística*" si no que se centran en detalles que no tienen nada que ver con el mundo técnico en general ni con el mundo de la programación en particular. Me gustaría compartir una reflexión: si para una tarea no usas tus genitales ni tu nacionalidad, etnia o color de piel significa que esa tarea es independiente de tus genitales, nacionalidad, etnia o color de piel.

Hay una tendencia reciente a describir el mundo del desarrollo de software (y la tecnología en general) como un ambiente hostil y cerrado a ciertos colectivos. Esto no es cierto, precisamente en un ambiente técnico y tecnológico es donde menos importancia tienen las características como la orientación sexual, el género, la etnia o el color de piel ya que ninguna de esas características influye en el trabajo intelectual que se realiza.

Por ello, las preguntas centradas en la orientación sexual, raza, etnia o color de piel están lejos de aportar una información interesante ni fomentan un debate que enriquezca a la comunidad, al contrario: fomentan un debate que no tiene que ver con la tecnología ni con el desarrollo de software y que suele polarizar las opiniones de manera violenta y nada constructiva.

Algunas personas usan estas características arbitrarias para dividir a la comunidad, en lugar de ignorar estas características (cuya influencia en la tecnología es nula) las señalan, las subrayan y las ponen en primer plano haciendo más difícil la integración y la normalización (no puede ser normal una cosa que te dedicas a señalar como excepcional).

Si esta insistencia en señalar no es suficiente, se buscan problemas donde no los hay, como lo que sucedió con el [estudio de GitHub](https://peerj.com/preprints/1733v1.pdf) sobre una presunta discriminación de mujeres sobre *Pull Requests*<sup>1</sup> que resultó ser inexistente.

A veces tengo la sensación (y quiero que esto se tome como una opinión personal) que hay gente que exige un trato especial en base a ciertas características porque no consiguen destacar en su contexto de no ser por auto-señalar dichas características. En general, esa gente tiene una manera de pensar similar y es bastante efectiva en inculcar estas ideas por lo que su entorno acaba pensando de una manera similar; pero como intentaba transmitir [James Damore en su *Google memo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%27s_Ideological_Echo_Chamber): La diversidad física (características físicas de los individuos) no implica diversidad de pensamiento.

Así que mi voto es en contra de añadir ciertas preguntas:

- Basta de preguntas sobre orientación sexual, raza o etnia, "minorías" o minusvalías.

#### Editado 12 Febrero 2020

Obviamente, era "*irresistible*" hacer dichas preguntas.

*Imagina que estás decidiendo entre dos ofertas de trabajo en el mismo lugar, con el mismo salario y beneficios. De los siguientes factores ¿Cuáles son los 3 MÁS importantes para ti?*.
[image]
Una de las opciones es "Diversidad de la compañía u organización". Sabemos que no se refieren a diversidad intelectual si no diversidad física (orientación sexual, raza o etnia, "minorías" o minusvalías). Aunque ninguna de las diversidades mencionadas por mi o por ellos debería importar para trabajar.

*¿Cuál de los siguientes te describe?, si es que lo hace alguna. Por favor, selecciona todas las que sean relevantes. Si prefieres no responder puedes dejar esta pregunta en blanco*. Respecto a si te "describes" como mujer, hombre u otro género abecedario.
[image]
Como dato estadístico puede llegar a ser interesante en algún contexto, pero como dato técnico es absurdo: nada de eso influirá en la capacidad técnica de nadie.

*¿Eres transgénero?*
[image]
Como dato estadístico puede llegar a ser interesante en algún contexto, pero como dato técnico es absurdo: nada de eso influirá en la capacidad técnica de nadie. Nótese que la opción estadísticamente menos común, es la primera.

*¿Cuál de los siguientes te describe?, si es que lo hace alguna. Por favor, selecciona todas las que sean relevantes. Si prefieres no responder puedes dejar esta pregunta en blanco*. Respecto a si te "describes" con alguna orientación sexual.
[image]
Como dato estadístico puede llegar a ser interesante en algún contexto muy específico, pero como dato técnico es absurdo: nada de eso influirá en la capacidad técnica de nadie. Nótese que la opción estadísticamente más común, no es la primera.

*¿Cuál de los siguientes te describe?, si es que lo hace alguna. Por favor, selecciona todas las que sean relevantes. Si prefieres no responder puedes dejar esta pregunta en blanco*. Respecto a cuál es la etnicidad que te describe.
[image]
Como dato estadístico puede llegar a ser interesante en algún contexto muy específico, pero como dato técnico es absurdo: nada de eso influirá en la capacidad técnica de nadie. Mención especial a la triplicidad de género en *Latino* y la especificidad de *Indígena*.

*¿Cuál de los siguientes te describe?, si es que lo hace alguna. Por favor, selecciona todas las que sean relevantes. Si prefieres no responder puedes dejar esta pregunta en blanco*. Respecto a si alguna minusvalía "te describe".
[image]
Dejando de lado el que el hecho de considerar que una minusvalía describe a una persona es bastante ofensivo, como dato estadístico puede llegar a ser interesante en algún contexto muy específico, pero como dato técnico es absurdo: nada de eso influirá en la capacidad técnica de nadie… en el peor de los casos podría llegar a influir en el rendimiento de alguien. Nótese que la opción estadísticamente más común, es la penúltima.

*¿Cuál de los siguientes te describe?, si es que lo hace alguna. Por favor, selecciona todas las que sean relevantes. Si prefieres no responder puedes dejar esta pregunta en blanco*. Respecto a si algún desorden psíquico "te describe".
[image]
Dejando de lado el que el hecho de considerar que un desorden psíquico describe a una persona es bastante ofensivo, como dato estadístico puede llegar a ser interesante en algún contexto muy específico, pero como dato técnico es absurdo: nada de eso influirá en la capacidad técnica de nadie… en el peor de los casos podría llegar a influir en el rendimiento de alguien. Nótese que la opción estadísticamente más común, es la penúltima.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Aquí](https://slatestarcodex.com/2016/02/12/before-you-get-too-excited-about-that-github-study/) un artículo (en inglés) que analiza dicho estudio.

---

---

---

I don't have any suggestion about new questions to ask, but I do have a suggestion about which questions stop asking.

Enough of questions about [sexual orientation](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-sexual-orientation), [race or ethnicity](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-race-and-ethnicity), ["minorities"](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-gender) or [disability status](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-disability-status); those questions cannot be seen as *technically fun/silly* instead involves topics with no relation with any technical background in general nor with the programming world in particular. I would like to share a thought: for a given task, if you're not using your genitalia, nationality, ethnicity or skin color then that task have no relation with your genitalia, nationality, ethnicity or skin color.

There's a recent trend to describe software development (and technology as a whole) like a hostile and unwelcoming environment for certain groups. That's not true, on technical and technological environments is where traits like gender, etnicity or skin color are less important because none of those traits have any influence on the intelectual task performed.

For that reason, questions around sexual orientation, race, ethnicity or skin color doesn't give any interesting background neither encourages discussions that enriches the community: instead, encourages discussions unrelated with technology or software development and polarizes individuals in a violent and destructive manner.

Some people focus on those arbitrary traits to create division amongst the community, they should be ignoring this traits (which doesn't influence in a technical level) but they underline them instead and pull them to the front making the integration and normalization harder (cannot see as normal anything that is continuously pointed out to be exceptional).

If pointing out is not enough, sometimes issues are searched where there are none, like the [GitHub study about discrimination against Pull Requests from women](https://peerj.com/preprints/1733v1.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, discrimination which turned out being nonexistent.

I want the following paragraph to be seen as a personal opinion: Sometimes I feel like there's people demanding special treatment according to certain traits because they don't achieve enough recognition without self-pointing those traits. Usually, this kind of people have similar views and they're quite effective imposing their views which is why on their workplaces more people ends up thinking alike; but as [James Damore tried to express on the Google memo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%27s_Ideological_Echo_Chamber): Diversity doesn't equal to Diversity of Thought.

So, if you ask me, I'll vote to stop asking certain questions:

- Enough of questions about sexual orientation, race or ethnicity, "minorities" or disability status.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Here](https://slatestarcodex.com/2016/02/12/before-you-get-too-excited-about-that-github-study/) you can read an article about the study.

Comment: Esta sugerencia merece ser traducida (con su correspondiente acreditación al autor) y publicada en el sitio principal.

Comment: Bien pensado, los que se obsesionan con la discrimicación tienden a ser los que más discriminan. La mejor forma de entendernos con los demás es que, cuando interactuemos, no lo hagamos pensando en raza, etnia, orientación sexual, etc.

Comment: @devconcept ¿Quién ha hablado de discriminación? (sólo he usado el término una vez en mi respuesta y era para referirme a un caso donde no se daba).

Comment: Como bien dice @DavidDPG, las sugerencias deberían ir en el post original, aqui no tienen mucho sentido ya que dudo que lleguen a los oidos (ojos) de quien tiene capacidad de decisión. No le auguro un buen recibimiento de todas maneras...

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster La discriminación es el tema de orden de las turbas políticas de hoy en día. Quizás no te das cuenta pero eso es lo que ellos leen cuando ven un post como el tuyo. Porque no lo publicas en inglés y me comentas los resultados. Como dice el buen Pikoh no creo que sea bien recibida.

Comment: @devconcept lo que hagan o dejen de hacer las turbas políticas no es el tema del hilo. Tampoco lo es la discriminación. Mi postura es dejar de hacer preguntas que no aportan nada positivo a la comunidad pero que en contrapartida opino que es probable que aporten algo negativo.

Comment: Por cierto, relacionado:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389461/2020-developer-survey-any-topic-suggestions?answertab=active#comment728415_389461

Comment: @Pikoh "*Como comunidad hispanohablante también podemos contribuir con algunas de las preguntas para la encuesta. Si deseas hacerlo, por favor, puedes hacerlo aquí en el apartado de respuestas con tu pregunta y posibles respuestas y su traducción al ingles (opcional)*".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si, eso pone en la publicación Rafael. Pero si te fijas en la original, no pone que se vayan a revisar los meta de otros sitios, por lo que dudo que nadie con responsabilidad lo vaya a ver. A no ser que Rafael tenga/tuviera la intención de publicarlas el mismo

Comment: ¿Cómo se recibió la contribución de PaperBirdMaster? No puedo encontrar su contribuciones al meta de SO sobre su perfil

Answer (score 4):

A mi me gustaría saber cómo está el tema de la seguridad de la información en el desarrollo de software. Cada día tenemos nuevas tecnologías, y todas significan nuevas *amenazas* u *oportunidades* en la seguridad. En el desarrollo nos enfocamos en las metodologías, las pruebas de funcionalidad, código limpio, patrones de diseño, etc., pero la seguridad es algo que normalmente no se toma en cuenta antes, durante ni después de que se entrega el software, *hasta que sucede algo*. Entonces si le ponemos atención, con costos altísimos (pueden significar hasta el cierre de la compañía).

- ¿Se toma en cuenta en tu compañía la seguridad al momento de realizar el análisis y diseño? (Si/No)
- ¿Se toma en cuenta en tu compañía la
  seguridad al momento de desarrollar? (Si/No)
- ¿Se toma en cuenta en tu compañía la seguridad en la etapa de pruebas, por ejemplo un análisis de vulnerabilidades del OWASP Top 10? (Si/No)